# SVG Animation should only start when on the right Page/ Part of the Website

Tags: javascript, css, svg, web-deployment, svg-animate

as the title already says, I need help figuring out how to make my SVG Animation 'wait' or to be more precise trigger at the right page/ part of the Website.

I was thinking about using javascript but due to the fact I'm not really good at it (yet ;D) I am asking here. Maybe something like, animation -name- should wait till user is on page -x- to start.

Any Tips would be amazing.

Kind Regards
Mika

Comment: Looking into IntersectionObserver should help here.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest think I can think of is to have a css class containing your animation and applying it to your HTMLElement with some JavaSript when your criteria is right. I don't understand exactyly what do you mean by "When it's on the right side" so I can't tell you how to exactly catch this situation in your code.